# getLocationOnScreen returns wrong values

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following 3 wrapped in a RelativeLayout (ignore the visibility="gone").

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dip"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

When I call `view.getLocationOnScreen(pos);`

I get back 0 for `pos[0]` and 219 for `pos[1]` even though none of them are at those (x,y) coordinates. It is puzzling that every ImageView gives me the same values especially considering they're in different locations. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

In your layout all image views are in state of "gone". So the getLocationOnScreen() method is returning the top-left corner position.

If you want to get the exact positions of the views change their visibility to "invisible" or "visible" as per your requirement.